# Android createCaptureSession freezes UI 2 seconds

Tags: android, video, record, mediarecorder

I am developing a video recording application. The moment I start recording a video, the screen hangs for two seconds but it doesn't give an error. I think it could be from the createCaptureSession method. I would be glad if you help. Thank you.

Here I do permissions checks and start recording (checkWriteStoragePermission()).
Here I am giving the necessary information for media recorder(setupMediaRecorder()).
The method from which the createCaptureSession process begins checkWriteStoragePermission().

```
    public void checkWriteStoragePermission() {
        mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                try {
                    createVideoFileName();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if (mIsTimelapse || mIsRecording) {
                    startRecord(true);
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                        try {
                            mMediaRecorder.prepare();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    mMediaRecorder.start();
                }
            } else {
                if (activity.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                    Toast.makeText(activity, "app needs to be able to save videos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                activity.requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PERMISSION_RESULT);
            }
        } else {
            try {
                createVideoFileName();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (mIsRecording || mIsTimelapse) {
                startRecord(true);
                mMediaRecorder.start();
            }
        }
    }

   private void setupMediaRecorder() throws IOException {
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE);
        mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
        mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(mVideoFileName);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(1000000);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(30);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoSize(mVideoSize.getWidth(), mVideoSize.getHeight());
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
        mMediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
        mMediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(mTotalRotation);
        mMediaRecorder.prepare();
    }


 private void startRecord(Boolean setupMediaControl) {
        try {
            if (mIsRecording) {
                if (setupMediaControl == true) {
                    setupMediaRecorder();
                }
            } else if (mIsTimelapse) {
                setupTimelapse();
            }
            SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture = mTextureView.getSurfaceTexture();
            surfaceTexture.setDefaultBufferSize(mPreviewSize.getWidth(), mPreviewSize.getHeight());
            Surface previewSurface = new Surface(surfaceTexture);
            Surface recordSurface = mMediaRecorder.getSurface();
            mCaptureRequestBuilder = mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_RECORD);
            mCaptureRequestBuilder.addTarget(previewSurface);
            mCaptureRequestBuilder.addTarget(recordSurface);

            mCameraDevice.createCaptureSession(Arrays.asList(previewSurface, recordSurface, mImageReader.getSurface()), new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onClosed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session) {
                    super.onClosed(session);
                }

                @Override
                public void onConfigured(CameraCaptureSession session) {
                    mRecordCaptureSession = session;
                    try {
                        mRecordCaptureSession.setRepeatingRequest(mCaptureRequestBuilder.build(), mPreviewCaptureCallback, mBackgroundHandler);
                    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                @SuppressLint("LongLogTag")
                @Override
                public void onConfigureFailed(CameraCaptureSession session) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onConfigureFailed: startRecord");
                }
            }, mBackgroundHandler);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does it proceed to record after the freeze or the app crashes?

Comment: There is no problem with video recording.

Comment: He is screen video recording but my app is recording front camera